# How to disable chrome web security from protractor on linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, security, protractor, e2e

How can we open chrome browser with disable web security from protractor on linux machine

I have tried following, works on windows but not on linux

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      useAutomationExtension: false,
      //args: ["--headless", '--disable-web-security', 'C:/Chrome dev session']
      args: ['--disable-web-security', 'C:/Chrome dev session']
    }
  },
```

Comment: linux won't have `C:/Chrome dev session` path

Comment: Then what should we have for linux? Path to which file?

Comment: I'm not sure what this path supposed to be. Is it location of your chromedriver?

Comment: Yes, it is but on windows, but do you know how to open chrome with disabled security on linux from protractor